# Can I get rid of AdMob test ads for iOS App Review?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I need to get rid of the "test mode" thing in a GADBannerView so I can comply with Apple's guidelines when I submit my app to the app store. I also need to do this so I can get screenshots of my app for the app store.

I have researched how to do this, but google says that you cannot get rid of the "test mode" for ads unless your app is on the app store.

Comment: Are you using a real `GADApplicationIdentifier` in your production app? If you're using a real one, it should not give you a "test mode" AD and instead, since your app is not approved and available on the App store yet. It will fail to load the real AD, so you can have a logic to check this and only display the AD view if it successfully loaded the AD. For screenshots, just temporary remove the AD while you're taking them

Comment: Run a TestFlight build; What ads do you see?  You should see real ads since you are running a release mode build; This is the same thing the Apple Reviewer will see

Comment: Did you ever get it working?  How did you fix it?  I had the same problem (flutter app) in ios.

Comment: Sadly no, I never fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I want to give a possible solution to the steps i have done. I use Flutter.

1. SDK to Pod file, below the target `'Runner' do`

Link to help:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

This is my POD file snippet:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

   # Add this line for google mobile ads
   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

2. Run `pod install --repo-update`
3. Update `info.plist` as described in below article

Link: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist

4. Initialize the mobile sdk in the `AppDeledate.swift` (again, i am using flutter)

This is my `AppDelegate.swift` file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMobileAds // Add this import for Google Mobile Ads


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

And everyhting else is depending on your framework, and i removed the test device from AdMob, also waited to get my app approved and linked it to the app store.